# Simple IO instructions on "read" command for new lisp user

Tags: io, lisp

I am a new lisp user. I have been trying to figure out how to use the lisp read command for about an hour by googling and looking for examples. I have been unsuccessful, and am finally throwing in the towel.

Can someone give me a very simple example of a lisp function that will accept 2 inputs, and add them?

My best attempt:

```
(defun func ()
(print "Enter first integer")
(read)
(print "Enter second integer")
(read)
(print (+ A B))
)
```

I have tried experimenting with `(read A)` or with a prefix to read `(format t “~A” string)` with no luck. All of the information on the internet that I have been looking for is extremely complicated, and I cannot make heads nor tails of it. Should it really be this hard? I may just be too familiar with bash/ksh/csh/sh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign the read input to your variables:

```
(defun func ()
  (print "Enter first integer") 
  (finish-output)
  (let ((a (read)))
    (print "Enter second integer")
    (finish-output)
    (let ((b (read)))
      (print (+ a b)))))
```

Comment: This works, but is there another way to assign the input to a variable than by having nested `let` statements?

Comment: What is it you don't like about `let`? Indentation?

Comment: since it is encapsulated, wont the a and b variables only be viable until you close the initial let clause?

Comment: Yes, that's the point, they are local to the let. There are alternatives, but this is the recommended way. Your function can always return their values to the caller, if necessary.

Comment: Common portability mistake: output can be buffered. You need to call `FINISH-OUTPUT` after the output functions, before reading. Also: `PRINT` is not the best function for output of text strings. Use `FORMAT`, `WRITE`or `WRITE-LINE`.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thanks, added `(finish-output)`.